# calling magento module class from external php file

Tags: module, magento-1

i have module in my magento

1: config.xml
code of config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>Inic_Catalog_Helper_Product_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_attributes>Inic_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes</product_view_attributes>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

2:view.php
community\Inic\Catalog\Helper\Product\view.php

code of view.php

```
class Inic_Catalog_Helper_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View
{
    public function gevalnow($param)
    {
      return $param
    }
}
```

now i have written custom code in my root folder say test.php

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$helper = Mage::helper('inic_catalog/product_view')->gevalnow('Standard');
print_r($helper);// get value from function in view.php
```

i get below error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inic_Catalog_Helper_Product_View' not found in /home/keviainc/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546**

how can i do it pls guide ??..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to see what is the tag for the helper in app/code/community/Inic/Catalog/etc/config.xml. Search for `<helpers>`. Most probably it is:

```
    <helpers>
        <inic_catalog>
            <class>Inic_Catalog_Helper</class>
        </inic_catalog>
    </helpers>
```

then you have to use:

```
Mage::helper('inic_catalog/product_view')->gevalnow();
```

You have to replace inic_catalog with the string from the config.xml (below `<helpers>` tag).

Comment: not working check my updated code

Comment: Please paste the config.xml.

Comment: paste config.xml see point 1: config.xml code of config.xml:

Comment: Please try with Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->gevalnow();